# How I can create this template in Android?

Tags: java, android, templates, view, styles

I need to create a template for android as follows:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29764789/app_example.png

Can anyone help me? Or guide me? A greeting and thank you very much

Comment: You cannot just come here and hope that somebody else does your work for you. Try it yourself, if you run into a specific problem which you cannot manage to solve yourself (after **trying** to solve it that is, I gotta stress the **try**) then you can come back here. If you don't know how to do it than Google it. Stack Overflow is not here to teach you programming.

Comment: Most people that post questions here somehow miss what this site is all about, I quote: "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for **professional and enthusiast programmers**".

Comment: @XaverKapeller I decided to write on this site to get my bearings and find a help

Comment: Yes well you should post a question here if you have an actual problem. I can just say again Stack Overflow is not here to teach you programming. If you don't know how to do it, than google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a problem where code is not necessarily the solution, maybe you should use photoshop to glue 2 images together in this way. It would be a lot easier, and obviously much less buggy. If you really want to do this in-app, you are going to have to at least get some rough code and make a rough attempt so that we have something to work with.

Comment: I've thought about doing images from photoshop but would not it be a problem the size of each mobile device screens?

Comment: @Adrian [**Link to the official Guide about supporting multiple screens sizes and densities**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: @Adrian No. Think about it, even if you did this twin image view thing. If size was a problem with photoshop, then it would probably be even more of a problem with weird diagonal image views. Just make sure that the images are of decent resolution, if they are too small they will look awful unless you leave them really small on the screen.

Comment: Thank you very much to you both, I'll try! regards